# Changing title automatically according to selected layer using QGIS composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm working on a project where I have to create different maps for the same area. I have lots of maps and each of them is related to a different theme, that I've grouped into different groups of layers as you can see in the image.
Each group of layers has a name that will be used as the map title. Because I have a lot of them, each time that a select a different group I want to change the map title automatically to have the same name as the layer group that is selected.

How I can do that?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

### For QGIS 2.18.x

In your composer label, go to `Item Properties > Insert an expression...`. Click the **Function Editor** tab and either create a new file or use an existing one (these are scripts which can execute some code). Use something like the following code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def func(feature, parent):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    lyr = root.findLayer(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0].id())
    group = lyr.parent().name()
    if group != '':
        return lyr.parent().name()
    else:
        return 'Group not found'
```

Then click *Load*. Switch to the **Expression** tab and type the name of the function, which in this example is:

```
func()
```

Hopefully now, when you click on a layer, the name of the group should show up.

[image: Screenshot]

---

*Note: you may need to click on the composer window for the name to be refreshed.*

---

---

### For QGIS 3.x

Similar to the above method but in the code, replace:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry
```

with:

```
QgsProject
```

So the code should read:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def func(feature, parent):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    lyr = root.findLayer(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0].id())
    group = lyr.parent().name()
    if group != '':
        return lyr.parent().name()
    else:
        return 'Group not found'
```

Comment: HI Joseph, thanks. I did what you indicated, but doesn't work. I did the function and after that I put the expression, but  this mensage appears: "the expression is invalid".  I refresh the qgis composer and I select and unselect the layer group, but nothing happens, in the title just appears the expression text "[%func()%]"

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Did you click `Load`? The expression text `[%func()%]` is correct but it should display the group names. Which QGIS version and platform are you using?

Comment: Yes, i click the Load. I am using Qgis 3.0.

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Then that may be the problem :). The solution posted works for QGIS 2.18, The name "Print Composer" changed to "Print Layout" in QGIS 3 hence why I assumed you were using the former. I'll edit the post if I can get it to work :)

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Fortunately it was a simple fix :). Replace `QgsMapLayerRegistry` with `QgsProject` and all should be well.

Comment: Joseph I had the same problem again. I replace the words, but doesn't work

Comment: @mauriciosantos - In what way does it not work? Do you receive an error or does the label not update?

Comment: The label not update, just appears the expression text " [%func()%]" in the title.

Comment: I load the function and I refresh the qgis composer and qgis project.

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Try placing `root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()` inside the function at the beginning and see if that helps.

Comment: Jhosep, I place inside the function and gives me an error when i load:"invalid syntax"

Comment: @mauriciosantos - It was probably an indentation error. I edited the code in the post, try copying/pasting it again into your function editor.

Comment: Jhosep, i had the some problem again :(

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Apologies but I cannot replicate your issue. It works fine for me, I am using QGIS 3.0.1 for Win 7 64-bit.

Comment: Jhosep don't worry, I'm grateful for your help. I close the qgis and a i restart the computer and now in the title appear the return message "Group not found". So maybe the problem is relate to the if statment, what do you think?

Comment: @mauriciosantos - When you change layers from QGIS, do you click the label title? That should refresh it.

Comment: Yes, i click. But nothing happens

Comment: Jhosep I've tried it several times, and have figured out that this only works when I click on a particular layer within the group layer. When I do this, the function returns the name of the group layer to layer belongs.

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Are there layers with the same name? That would cause issues.

Comment: No. What i have is subgroups inside each goup, but the subgroups also have differents name.

Comment: @mauriciosantos - Sorry, didn't see your message. The code still works for me, even with subgroups. Not sure what the problem is, apologies.