# Qgis Changing title automatically according to selected sublayer using QGIS composer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a group in QGIS with around 20 sublayers. I would like to automatically update the label in my Layout based on the sublayer I have selected, so i don't have to do this manually.

[I have found this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284613/changing-title-automatically-according-to-selected-layer-using-qgis-composer)

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def func(feature, parent):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    lyr = root.findLayer(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0].id())
    group = lyr.parent().name()
    if group != '':
        return lyr.parent().name()
    else:
        return 'Group not found'
```

This somewhat does what I want, but it shows the parent name. And I would like for it to show the name of the selected child. I'm a student and just started learning QGIS.

Comment: So you want the layername?

Comment: yes. The layers inside the group. I thought they were called sublayers, but seems like they're called layers indeed.

Comment: Your question helped me a lot haha.                                                                       
all i had to change was  return lyr.parent().name() in return lyr.name()

Answer (score 1):

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def func(feature, parent):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
    lyr = root.findLayer(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer.name())[0].id())
    group = lyr.parent().name()
    if group != '':
        return lyr.name()
    else:
        return 'Group not found'
```